# Subclassing a Custom Control when doing it right is not possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, servercontrols

I have a stand alone custom control that is extensively deployed.

It has one public property (`ClientIdentifier`) and two methods (`OnLoad` and `RenderContents`)

Over the years there have been some `if` clauses added to handle certain client specific situations, but now I really need to subclass it.  The issue is that I can't break the API.

I have full access to the code, but I can't change the call from the website.

My thinking:

Use `Onload` as a Factory method, creating another POCO extends interface as a private member based on the `ClientIdentifier` -- call it `SubControl`.

In `RenderContents`, simply past through to `SubControl.RenderContents(writer)`

Is this the appropriate technique?

Or is there a better idea? (other than throwing it out and starting fresh.)

Comment: Can you decorate it, so it will not break the signature and for each client case it will use specific decorator?
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/decorator